# CE 1.9.2.4 on virtual server: SOAP-API V1 not working

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v1

Problem: i have a virtual server with Plesk (Ubuntu 14.04) and the SOAP-API not working. I have many trouble with this issue, because i have a second server with the same configuration and there no issues. In my etc/hosts is the server name `127.0.0.1 www.example.com example.com example localhost`.

Following error cames from the

```
SOAP-Script: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://www.example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "https://www.example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1"
```

A cache refresh will not affect.

Have anybody the breaking idea? Thanks!